# Batch/Bulk Insert ADO.Net collection in MapXtreme Table

Tags: mapinfo, performance

I am working on MapXtreme 7.1 and using MICommand to insert data in a table. I have more then 10,000 records and i am inserting these using a loop. That is

```
Geometry = new MapInfo.Geometry.Point(coordSys, new MapInfo.Geometry.DPoint(Longitude, Latitude));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Geometry;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = new MapInfo.Styles.SimpleInterior(36, System.Drawing.Color.RosyBrown);
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into MyTable(MI_Geometry,MI_Style,latitude,longitude) values(geometry, style, latitude, longitude);
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here MI_Geometry and MI_Style are of types MIDbType.FeatureGeometry and MIDbType.Style respectively. The above code is working in a loop and it is inserting all of my data into that table.

The problem is, it is taking too much time to populate. Is there any way to bulk/batch insert or direct populate this table from my .Net collection through some sort of binding etc. My first requirement is to draw more then 10,000 points on Map from my collection.